# Reading candlesticks and identifying trends

Tags: stocks, starting-out-investing, technical-analysis

Firstly, I am pretty new to investing and have only been doing it for a few months now.
I want to ask, as a long-term investor into safe instruments like ETFs, what are some of the best identifying candlestick patterns in order to get ahead?

I've also heard of the market being "bullish" and "bearish" but I am not sure what these mean exactly.
I wasn't sure where I was able to ask this since most investing communities on Reddit for example seem either too "memey", or too serious to involve myself.

So the questions are:

1. What does a "bullish" stock mean. And what does a "bearish" stock mean?
2. What are identifying candlestick patterns for long-term trading that I should watch for in order to choose when to buy or sell?
3. As a long-term, new investor, should I even care about the day-to-day or minute-to-minute candlestick patterns?

Also, one last question. I was looking around at different candlestick patterns and came across a very interesting pattern of a stock with very long candlesticks in a repeating pattern. What would this sort of pattern mean in terms of short-term/long-term?

Weird candlestick pattern:

[image: Weird candlestick pattern]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a long-term, new investor, should I even care about the day-to-day
> or minute-to-minute candlestick patterns?

Candlestick patterns are used by people who are trying to time the market. They are wanting to guess when would be the best time to buy or sell.

If you are a long term investor, then the best thing to invest in is index funds. The best time is now. And the best time to sell is when it has meet your goals.

As to bullish and bearish. Bull means the market/index/stock is going up in price. Bearish means they are going down in price.

Comment: This is fantastic information. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to become financially literate.  The only way to do that is to start reading books.

Google:

- Best technical analysis books
- Best investing books

When you get an idea of the lay of the land, figure out what makes sense to you and for you.  Asking others what they think is best is folly.

Comment: Given OP asks "As a long-term, new investor, should I even care about the day-to-day or minute-to-minute candlestick patterns?" technical analysis might not be the best start, regardless of (non-)belief in its efficacy.

Comment: One can be a long term investor and utilize technical analysis.  But part from that,  his question addressed both topics as did I.